# как replace'ом убрать с ссылки некоторые слова?

Tags: php, opencart3.x

Есть ссылка такого типа, незнаю почему то средствами движка и правкой кода не получилось поправить чтобы она выводилась без page, решил пойти другим путем, может сделать replace ? вот код и как я его вывожу, подскажите пожалуйста как убрать тут все что /?page=любая цифра

```
<link href="http://www.site.ru/stroitelnye-materialy/?page=8" rel="canonical" />

 $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category_info['category_id'], true), 'canonical');
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно регуляркой сделать замену, например, так:

```
$link = '<link href="http://www.site.ru/stroitelnye-materialy/?page=8" rel="canonical" />';
$text = preg_replace('/\?page=(\d{1,})/', '', $link);
echo $text;
```

Comment: А как это можно добавить в $this->document?     link выводит уже готовый через twig? а $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category_info['category_id'], true), 'canonical');  вот так вот он выводит уже